# How to create a shortcut to a unit test from a comment?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, comments, javadoc

I would like to add a shortcut to a specific unit test from my class level comment.  This way a developer can quickly navigate to a test within their IDE.

Using IntelliJ, I added the following to the class comment for "MyClass":

```
/**
* @see com.my.address.AnotherClass
* @see com.my.address.MyClassTests
* {@link com.my.address.MyClassTests#nameOfMyTest NameOfMyTest}
*/
```

IntelliJ presents this error for the two shortcuts that reference the tests:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'com.my.address.MyClassTests' less... (⌘F1) 
This inspection points out unresolved references inside javadoc
```

Is it possible to present a shortcut to a unit test from comment?  If so, how?

--- additional info (Jan.28/2015) ---

This is my module setting in IntelliJ for this project:

[image]

Comment: This was one of my favorite capabilities of RubyMine. https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/navigating-between-test-and-test-subject.html Looks like it's the same keystroke in IDEA for Java, but you want a more explicit link, right?

Comment: Agreeing with @unigeek - ideally your IDE allows you to jump to the unit test without needing a comment. NetBeans does this with a shortcut key. Have you checked whether IntelliJ can do it too?

Comment: You can, but I'd like to reference a specific test within the test class, not just navigate to the class and then search for a specific test.  If I can get the JavaDoc to work, then when it is generated the link will also be included in the documentation.  Linking to a test would also help identify if relevant/important tests are removed.  This is important when a test represents a BDD inspired requirement.  I could just write the test info a plain comment, but a direct link to a test would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are in the same package you don't need the package name, but you do need a `#` between the class name and the method name:

```
{@link MyClassTests#NameOfMyTest()}
```

Comment: I receive the same "Cannot resolve symbol" error message using this technique.

Comment: @TERACytE I'm not sure why that would be. The more complete version would be to include the parens (and the types of any parameters, especially if you need to match a particular overload), but I thought that was optional. I've added the parens to my answer, and I'll give it a try in IntelliJ (I'm running Eclipse right now, but also have IntelliJ installed).